# How to Read Form data in erlang API handler

Tags: api, erlang, xmpp, multipartform-data, ejabberd

I am building a custom HTTP module in ejabberd which is basically coded in erlang. Clients are sending form data in the request. How can i parse or read form data in the API handler in erlang .

Thanks

Comment: Definitively not enough information. You should at least give an example of what you get at the stage where you are blocked,and how you expect to transform it.

Comment: I am searching for the function whixh can parse form data and i can read it. Just like any JSON parser i want form data parser. Thats the start and that's where i am stuck.